# Backbone.js : initialize Model with dynamic name

Tags: backbone.js

In backbone.js I can initialize a model with

```
var model = new MyModel();
```

But I would like to initialize a model with a dynamic name - like "MyDynamicModel". How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you like to give it a dynamic name? What's the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wrapper object to get somewhat similar outcome.

```
var wrapper = {
    "myDynamicName": new MyModel(),
    "myOtherModel": new MyModel()
    }
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
wrapper["myDynamicName"].render();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your models are declared globally (on the `window` object), then you can use the square bracket notation:

```
var Model = window[modelName]; // Assuming modelName is the dynamic name of your model
var model = new Model();
```

Or, if your models are namespaced under something like `App.Models`:

```
var Model = App.Models[modelName];
var model = new Model();
```

As a last resort, you can use Javascript's `eval` function, but in general this should be avoided.

```
var Model = eval(modelName);
var model = new Model();
```